# -version with java and javac

Tags: java

The `-version` option can be used with both `java` and `javac`. Whats the difference?

Comment: Have you run them to find out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each reports the version of the program it's running. `java` (the Java virtual machine) and `javac` (the Java compiler) are separate programs. It would be perfectly possible to have your path set up so that they weren't from the same installed package... and anyway, it's handy to be able to be absolutely sure that you've got the right version when you run something.

Comment: Exactly. At one point my desktop machine was set up this way; the OS had put a /usr/bin/java symlink in, pointing to *its* favorite JRE, and my own JDK installation came later in the path.  When weird things were happening, at one point I ran both `java -version` and `javac -version` and immediately discovered the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Java:**

```
jonathan@bespin:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_16"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

**Javac:**

```
jonathan@bespin:~$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_16
```

Comment: +1 Exemplary; consider <pre></pre> tags to eliminate spurious syntax coloring.